# import javax.crypto.Cipher on ubuntu fails in eclipse with JDT

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-jdt

I am using the Eclipse JDT to build/run liferay for hot deployment & debugging according to those steps:

http://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/1071674/Eclipse;jsessionid=3A2A0014C6A14D67C4A437AD127296A0.node-1

Suddenley after restarting my Ubuntu VM after installing Updates the import of javax.crypto fails.

I googled a lot but no real solution by now.
Meanwhile I can build after adding jce.jar to my jdks external jars (Eclipse-Window-Prefernces-Installed JREs - Select JRE - Edit - Add External Jars)

This helps for Building but not when launching from the Debugger

???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After starting eclipse with the `-clean` flag in the `eclipse.ini` everything runs fine again.

I further noticed, that the Restore Defaults button in Preferences -> Java > ... -> Edit JRE
now adds a lot more jars than before.

It now consists of the following jars - but adding them by hand did not help:

```
jre/lib/rt.jar
jre/lib/jsse.jar
jre/lib/jce.jar
jre/lib/charset.jar
jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
```

Using JDK 1.5 here